# Selenium not recognized in xampp

Tags: python, selenium, xampp

I am trying to run some python script in xampp Apache server. I have installed python 3.10 and selenium with pip install. When I run test.py on localhost i get this error from Apache: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'\r: C:/xampp/htdocs/Project_php/index/test.py.
When i run the script from terminal, everything works fine.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe xampp uses own Python and you have to install Selenium in this Python. in xampp you could run python script `import sys ; print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python` and later use it to install module `/full/path/to/python -m pip install selenium`

Comment: I've tried that but no luck.. it says library already installed.

Comment: did you run `sys.executable` using `xampp`? it may use different Python which has different path.